# ExtJS -- tag field ignoring forceSelection flag on enter/blur

Tags: extjs

I'm using the Ext.form.field.Tag component. I have configured

```
createNewOnEnter:true,
createNewOnBlur:true, 
forceSelection:true
```

but if I type in a value that's not the in the dropdown list/store records and tab-out or click enter the value gets selected. I want the value to be selected on enter/blur ONLY if it exists in the dropdown. But when createNewOnEnter and createNewOnBlur are set to true, forceSelection becomes false. I verified this by setting a debugger in the "change" event handler.

I dont have a fiddle but you can copy paste the above config into the live editor in the API Docs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Tag)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some configurations that are incompatible with each other, and ExtJS does not provide for all thinkable configurations of components (although they try, but then, Tagfield is quite new). This is the relevant part of the form/field/Tag.js file that explains your experience:

```
if (me.createNewOnEnter || me.createNewOnBlur) {
    me.forceSelection = false;
}
```

To get what you want, you would have to override some parts of the tag field definition to suit your needs. You should look into overriding the `assertValue` and the `onKeyUp` functions.